# Deploying AzureRM Web App with VSTS automatically

Tags: azure, continuous-deployment

I am trying to follow https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/04/01/build-and-deploy-azure-web-apps-using-team-foundation-serverservices-vnext-builds/.

I have no issues deploying the web app manually from Visual Studio using PublishingSettings and Publish option. I just want to automate the process and I am stuck at this step:
 [image]

The article clearly advises

> Select the Certificate Based connection. This is very important when
>   you are trying to deploy. Credential based Microsoft Account
>   (@outlook, @hotmail) are no longer supported and only Organizational
>   accounts are. Even then, if they use Two-Factor Authentication(2FA),
>   the build will fail trying to connect to Azure.

This is correct and if I try to use Credentials, my deployment fails with *unknown_user_type: Unknown User Type
There was an error with the Azure credentials used for deployment.* message.

So >> Certificate. But in my PublishSettings file there is no Management Certificate and as per [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2016/11/28/azure-management-certificates-and-publishing-setting-file-with-csp-subscriptions/)

> Azure Management Certificates and Publishing Setting files (...) are
>   only intended and limited to manage Azure Service Management (ASM)
>   resources

I tried this option:
[image]

But VSTS is not connected to the Azure environment (considering that Azure belongs to one Customer and VSTS to another, is it even possible?).

My questions:
* Is it the deployment somehow possible with PublishSettings file?
* Should the "Credentials" option work if I am using an organizational account Me@Company.com?
* How else can I try?

EDIT

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your solution could be creating a service principal in Azure and connect it to VSTS. The automatic Build from VSTS should then be published to Azure automatically. Here you find how to setup the service principal and connect it to VSTS: https://www.petri.com/connect-visual-studio-team-services-azure-using-service-principal-name

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have managed to set the SPN and add a new RM connection, but I cannot use the connection in Azure Web App Deployment step. I see only Azure Classic connections there ("gg" one).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure right now, whether you are using TFS or VSTS?! When I publish a Web App in VSTS, the ARM Service Endpoints works well: 
[image]